# How to write formula to grow all dynamic text field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

> Hi Experts,
>
> Is there any way to automatically grow the content of dynamic text
>   field in crystal report. I will give you an example this way.
>
> I have values to display in crystal report as (which we fetch dynamically fromt the database) 
>   Employee_ID, Employee_name, Employee_address
>
> Now, the Employee_ID, Employee_name would be ok. But for
>   Employee_address the value can be anything from the database, i.e. it
>   can be lengthy also(like with 80 charectors also). That is it will come in next row and 
>   overlap the below the row column ('address') value.
>
> Now, is there any way(or formula), when one dynamic text field grows
>   like address, then previous two Employee_ID and Employee_address
>   should grow automatically and for next row the data should not overlap
>   also.
>
> Please give ideas.
>
> Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just mark the desired fields `Can Grow?` property to `true` and let Crystal Reports handle the work?

Comment: yes, it can be done but if we know that only one field will grow. And then why we use can grow field to all the fields. if the report has 10 values to show. that's why i want to know is there any way i can apply in crystal report through which if one field grows, the other fields grows pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark the three fields `can grow`, then each field will expand (vertically) as necessary to accommodate the data.  If the field does NOT need to expand, it won't.  Moreover, if the three fields are arranged side-by-side in the same `details` section, there will be no overlap--either horizontally or vertically.

If you are trying to always bottom-align the three fields, regards of the vertical size of any of the fields (the address field in your example seems to be the issue), then you have a different problem:

```
Relative Positions
This option allows you to lock the relative position of a report object next to a grid object within a section. For example, if you place a text object one centimeter to the right of a cross-tab object, during report generation the program will push the text object to the right, so that the one centimeter space is maintained regardless of the width of the cross-tab object.
Note: 
Only horizontal locking is possible. If you need to preserve relative vertical positioning, you should create a new report section.
Once Relative Positions is selected for a section, you can no longer drag objects to new positions within that section. To change an object's position, use the Object Size and Position dialog box.
Relative positioning applies only to objects placed to the right of grid objects (that is, objects that can grow horizontally).
```